# Javascript: variable undefined according to IE

Tags: internet-explorer, variables, select, dojo, undefined

I use Dojo to generate a form with selects. However, I get an undefined variable with IE. My code is as follow:

```
var listeRef = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore(
        { url : 'label_ref_json?where='+escape(' 1 ORDER BY label_ref_contents ASC') }
    );
```

and then:

```
<input 
    dojoType = "dijit.form.ComboBox"
    store = "listeRef"
    searchAttr = "label_ref_contents"
    name = "ref"
    id = "ref" 
    autoComplete = "true" 
    query = "{label_ref_contents: '*'}"
    value = "1"
    onChange = "ref_change();"
    required = "true"
    regExp = "^\d{8}[a-zA-Z]{2}$"
/>
```

IE says `listeRef` is undefined, would you see why please ? Thanks very much

Comment: Yikes...are you posting SQL to your server from Javascript...?

Comment: posting SQL from javascript === say welcome to hackers

Comment: Hard to tell with the code posted, but I would guess that dojo is parsing the widget before your script is executing.  Therefore, when the parser looks for the store it is not there.

Comment: No, I use Ajax and a MVC model to create entries in the database. 
It is weird since the `listeRef` is declared at the beginning of the same file.

Comment: I tried by putting the declaration just above the use in the input and it doesn't complain any more. It still so weird, I'm going to test if the whole page could work like this but I'm sceptic.